Deploy Spring boot Maven 3 project on Railway using with java 21
I am trying to deploy my Spring boot Maven project on Railway but I am getting ERROR: docker.io/library/maven:3-openjdk-21: not found. I am using java 21 and when try to deploy the app on Railway it give me that error. First I tried to deployed the app without using Dockerfile and it say Java version 21 is not supported. So I created a Dockerfile so Railway can use that file and I got this error docker.io/library/maven:3-openjdk-21: not found. I am not sure if this Dockerfile is right or not.
FROM maven:3-openjdk-21 AS build-stage
WORKDIR /allinsoccer
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline


# Package stage
COPY ./src ./src
RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM openjdk:21-jdk AS production-stage
WORKDIR /allinsoccer
COPY --from=build-stage /allinsoccer/target/*.jar allinsoccer.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/allinsoccer/allinsoccer.jar"]

And this is the error message I am getting from Railway
[Region: us-west1]

=========================

Using Detected Dockerfile

=========================


context: 8e98465b1d12492815747366def8cc5f

#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver



#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile



#1 transferring dockerfile: 426B done

#1 DONE 0.0s



#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3-openjdk-21



#2 ERROR: docker.io/library/maven:3-openjdk-21: not found



#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:21-jdk



#3 CANCELED

-----

> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3-openjdk-21:

-----



Dockerfile:1

-------------------

1 | >>> FROM maven:3-openjdk-21 AS build-stage

2 |     WORKDIR /allinsoccer

3 |     COPY pom.xml .

-------------------

ERROR: failed to solve: maven:3-openjdk-21: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3-openjdk-21: docker.io/library/maven:3-openjdk-21: not found

I am using Maven 3.1.6 and openjdk-21

Obviously is your reference to docker wrong: docker pull maven:3.9-eclipse-temurin-21-alpine (check https://hub.docker.com/_/maven)
